# Coconut water from mature coconut

Tags: coconut

I recently bought a green, and a brown coconut (different stages of maturation). I drunk the liquid from the green, young one, which is apparently what you are supposed to do, and it tasted terrible. It was sourish not sweet at all, and had almost like a carbonated feel to it. However, water from the brown coconut (mature) tasted delicious and sweet, and left me much more satisfied. Is there a reason for this, because this is contrary to what I read online.

Answer (score 0):

All coco's are created different. If it is too young then definitely sour.I like them from our trees with 1/4 of spoon meet in them...a treat after you drink them. so I think you want a medium aged coco.

Comment: A quarter *inch* of coconut meat, or what?